# How do I fix my speed score on shopify when it says "image elements do not have explicit width and height"? Can this be done within shopify?

Tags: shopify, diagnostics, pagespeed-insights

I use only 5x7 images for my product pictures on my website. I'm currently trying to boost my speed score which is in the low 30s. There is not a place to select the size image I'm using when I uploaded the images and didn't realize I needed to input it in the back end. This is just one of the many problems I'm having but I feel like this going to be a simple fix if I could find where/how to input the information. I cannot find any coding already in back side about the pictures at all so I could just fill in the width and height. It's also possible I don't know where to find it/ looking in the wrong place.

I have tried looking videos up on youtube and reading Shopify answers but there is no direct answer to this problem. I know nothing about coding and most of the videos were very advanced people talking about this issue and there wasn't a straight forward answer. I've talked with a team of people about this problem a few months ago but they cant figure it out or haven't tried because no one got back to me. I'm willing to learn about coding if that's what this takes to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The image sizes must be specified in the source code.
It should look like something like that in the end:

```
<img src="monimage.jpg" width="500" height="700" alt="Image prompt">
```

In this example, the width of the image is set to 500x and the height to 700.